# Admin properties with open graph tags

Tags: facebook-like, admin, facebook-opengraph

I have a question regarding the like button on my website (http://www.lisasmit.tk). I had this like button for while, but now I would like to add Open Graph Tags to my site, so the like will show up in other people's likes and so that I can send messages to the people who liked my page.

Now I have this problem that I do not see a "admin" function next to my like button, nor can I get into the adminsection on my facebook page. I have added all the meta-tags (as far as I know) underneath the  section, and I liked and unliked my page several times, but still nothing shows up.

I have used the statistics page (https://www.facebook.com/insights/), but I can't get any results there. The error mentions that there are no admindata found in the root of my page.

Also, I used the facebook debugger which mentions "Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed" after I entered my url:

- Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly
  provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
- Inferred  Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even
  if a value can be inferred from other tags.
- Inferred Property:The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a
  value can be inferred from other tags.

These are the meta-tags I have added in my HTML section:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

    <meta property="og:title" content="Lisa Smit" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.lisasmit.tk" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="URLIMAGE" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Lisa Smit" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="MYFBCODE" />
```

Hopefully someone can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

The dot.tk domain actually iframes your site! so even if it shows that you are on lisasmit.tk, you are actually on http://lisasmit.tumblr.com/ ..

[Click here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://lisasmit.tk/) to see what facebook sees on your site

try giving your `og:url as http://lisasmit.tumblr.com/` and try adding a description meta tag,

```
<meta property="fb:description" content="Lisasmit description" />
```

Also change your like code :

Enter http://lisasmit.tumblr.com/ in the debug tool to debug your actual site.After you fix this, the errors should go away.

Comment: I see, thank you! 
I've tried this before, too. But as you mentioned I have to change the url in my like code, which will bring my like count back to zero (not that I have this much likes, but still). The reason I got a dot.tk domain was actually to get rid of the .tumblr.com part, but as I have to change the url's again the like will show up as .tumblr.com and not as my domainname (since this is actually only framing my tumblrsite, I assume)? Is there any way to change this, or do I just have to accept the fact that it will stay this way with tumblr and dot.tk?

Comment: OK, the short answer i can give is ,if tumblr permits you to change custom domain,  you need to use a DNS server and use a dot.tk domain. I know dot tk can be cofigured to do this by adding name servers of your host.